# Kotlin Multiplatform: Call constructor of generic type

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, kotlin-multiplatform

I have an inline function with a reified generic type T and I need to be able to create an instance of this T class by calling it's empty constructor inside the function. Something like this:

```
inline fun <reified T> createObject(): T{
 // call constructor of T and return
}
```

In reality I'm doing more things in the function, but this represents the problem I am facing.

Apparently since this is in the multiplatform module, I do not have access to the reflection method's I'd normally use to do this in pure Android. Wondering if there are any ways to get this to work. Because currently my code looks very ugly: I'm sending a function to this function that returns the instance so I can operate with it, therefore I need to manually call empty constructors everywhere in my app. This would simplify it so much!

Comment: you could create something like [this from koin di](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/main/core/koin-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/koin/core/module/dsl/FactoryOf.kt) where they had created a bunch of functions that can take a reference to constructor. that could be `inline fun <reified T> createObject(construct: () -> T): T = construct()` and invocation `createObject(::MyClass)`

Comment: @V-master if the function does nothing but call the function you pass to it and return the result, it's kind of useless. It's just a more verbose way of calling a constructor.

Comment: You really want to have `createObject<MyObject>()` all over your code instead of the natural, idiomatic, and concise `MyObject()`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 as I said, I'm doing other things inside the method, but that's not really relevant to the question, so I omitted it. Calling the constructor is just one part of the logic.

Comment: @V-master this is what I am doing already, but would be super nice if I could avoid calling ::MyClass manually, and have a generic logic that uses the reified type T to do it.

Comment: you can always create `mapOf<KClass<out Any>, () -> Any>(Date::class to ::Date)` and function will just execute saved factory `inline fun <reified T: Any> createObject() = factories[T::class]!!.invoke() as T`. Kotlin can then guess type from variable you are writing it on `val d: Date = createObject()`. It is basically what Dependency Injection like Koin can do for you - just declare dependency as factory instead of singleton - you will have then additional possibilities like passing extra parameters etc

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work without reflection.

Manually calling empty constructors is good and correct.  Do that.

(Additionally, reflection performs absolutely awfully in pure Android; you shouldn't do it there either.)